# Extended intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$. Suppose $t_1,t_2,...,t_n$ are $n$ positive real numbers such that $t_1+t_2+\dots+t_n = 1$. And assume $x_1,x_2,...,x_n \in [a,b]$. Show that there exists a point $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c) = t_1f(x_1) + t_2f(x_2) + \dots + t_nf(x_n)$.

My idea is to use the maximum-minimum theorem to show that the function achieves a maximum and minimum in the interval $[a,b]$, say max at $M$ and min and $N$.

Then $f(c)$ will be between $f(M)$ and $f(N)$ (just change all the $f(x)$ to $f(M)$ and since the $t$s add up to $1$), so we can use the intermediate value theorem.

Is my idea correct?

Comment: That looks fine.

Comment: Actually, you only need the maximum and minimum of the values $f(x_k)$, $k=1,...,n$ and not of the full function.

Comment: but i think u need the theorem to say that there exists a max and min

Comment: Here's a short sketch of a proof: find the i,j where $f(x_i)$ and $f(x_j)$ are min and max in ${f(x_1),...}$.  Show that $t_1 f(x_1) + ...$ is between the min and max.  Then use intermediate value theorem.